# How to use a boolean for Scrapy item loader

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use an item loader with Scrapy 0.24.5. When I use the add_item() method it throws an exception if I want to use a boolean or integer.

```
item.add_value('full_update', 1)
item.load_items()
```

produces the following error:

```
ValueError: Error with output processor: field='full_update' value=[1] error='TypeError: expected string or buffer'
```

I understand it's looking for a string. But I need to store a boolean value in my mongodb.

Is there another item loader method that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the add_value() method. It was that one of my output processors was expecting a string value which the `full_update` field was being run through.

In my `items.py` I added `output_processor=Identity()` to my full_update field and it now works:

```
class ProductsItem(scrapy.Item):
    full_update = scrapy.Field(output_processor=Identity())

class ProductsItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = ProductsItem
    default_output_processor = Compose(TakeFirst(), remove_tags, lambda v: replace_escape_chars(text=v, replace_by=' '), lambda v: v.encode('utf-8'), lambda v: ' '.join(v.split()))
pass
```